# ¿función para que al presionar enter cambie de input y no accione form? - javascript nativo

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una función:

```
function validarLetras(e){
    tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if (tecla == 13 || tecla == 8 || tecla == 9 || tecla == 28 || tecla == 15 || tecla == 37 || tecla == 39) {
            return true;
        }
    patron = (/[a-z A-Z \ñ \Ñ]/);
    tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    return patron.test(tecla_final);
}
```

En un `<input>` `onkeypress` funciona lo que son las letras, pero no sirve el `Enter`, y en otros formularios el `Enter` me hace enviar los datos del `<form>`.

Necesito una funcion o forma de poder que al momento de dar `enter`, me envíe al `<input>` siguiente sin que este `envíe` datos del `<form>`. Con javascript nativo preferiblemente.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer uso de `focus()`, que cuando se aprete enter se haga `focus` en el siguiente `input`.

```js
document.getElementById('inputFirst').addEventListener('keydown', inputCharacters);

function inputCharacters(event) {
 
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById('inputSecond').focus();
  }

}
```

```html
<input id='inputFirst'>
<input id='inputSecond'>
```

Comment: lo convertí en funcion:
`function nextFocus(inputF, inputS) {
    document.getElementById(inputF).addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            document.getElementById(inputS).focus();
        }
    });
}`
funciona en atributo onkeydown="nextFocus(this.name, "siguienteIdElement")", no sé por que no funciona onkeypress.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('inputFirst').addEventListener('keydown', inputCharacters);

function inputCharacters(event) {
 
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById('inputSecond').focus();
  }

}
```

```html
<input id='inputFirst'>
<input id='inputSecond'>
```

```js
function nextFocus(inputF, inputS) {
  document.getElementById(inputF).addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      document.getElementById(inputS).focus();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" onkeypress="nextFocus('input1', 'input2')"><br>
<input type="text" id="input2" onkeypress="nextFocus('input2', 'input3')"><br>
<input type="text" id="input3" onkeypress="nextFocus('input3', 'input4')"><br>
<input type="text" id="input4"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías solucionarlo así:

- Para detectar la tecla presionada deberías utilizar [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key), ya que [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) esta deprecado.
- Para evitar que se envíe el formulario deberías utilizar [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

### Ejemplo:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(evt) {

  // Si el evento NO es una tecla Enter
  if (evt.key !== 'Enter') {
    return;
  }
  
  let element = evt.target;

  // Si el evento NO fue lanzado por un elemento con class "focusNext"
  if (!element.classList.contains('focusNext')) {
    return;
  }

  // AQUI logica para encontrar el siguiente
  let tabIndex = element.tabIndex + 1;
  var next = document.querySelector('[tabindex="'+tabIndex+'"]');

  // Si encontramos un elemento
  if (next) {
    next.focus();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    Campo 1
    <input type="text" tabindex="1" class="focusNext">
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    Campo 2
    <input type="text" tabindex="2" class="focusNext">
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    Campo 3
    <input type="text" tabindex="3" class="focusNext">
  </label>
  <br>
  <button tabindex="4">Enviar</button>
</form>
```