# input al dar enter busque sin tener que presionar el botón

Tags: html, botón, mouseenter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]buenas tardes comunidad espero me puedan ayudar
quiero activar el cuando precione enter se busque sin necesidad de darle click al boton
gracias

```
<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-3 bsc-boton'>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-src-index" onclick="buscaDato();"> <?php echo _("Encuentra");?> </button></div>
```

[introducir la descripción del vínculo aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126895/funci%C3%B3n-para-que-al-presionar-enter-cambie-de-input-y-no-accione-form-javasc)

Comment: Hola. ¿Cómo que cuando se presione el enter? ¿Dónde, en un cuadro de texto o algo así?

Comment: dándole enter al teclado

Comment: Ya, pero ¿sobre qué **elemento** exactamente? La escucha de eventos debe asignarse a elementos en concreto. Dicho eso, ¿qué has intentado / investigado al respecto?

Comment: al llenar este         <input type='hidden' id='coo'>
darle enter al teclado busque el elementro

Comment: ¿Y, cómo se le va a dar enter, si ese `input` está oculto `type='hidden'`? ¿Lo haces visible de algún modo? ¿Cómo? Por favor, explícate y agrega lo que has intentado y qué problemas tienes con el código implementado.

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-src-index" onclick="buscaDato();"> <?php echo _("Encuentra");?> </button></div>
 ahi sale mitad es un boton y la otra es un boton agregre como se ve

Comment: Edita la pregunta agregando los cambios que realizaste, no lo escribas aquí, ya que es zona de comentarios, de esa forma podemos entender mejor tu problema.